# Conditionally load public and admin code with AJAX working on both sides

Tags: plugins, ajax, conditional-tags

I'm trying to conditionally load my front-end and admin area code, so the file and class that creates admin area will on load on admin side and file and class that is needed to be run on front-end will run only on front-end and won't touch anything on admin area.

I tried to use `is_admin()` conditional:

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    require_once(plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'public/class-public.php');
    $this->Public = new Public();
} else {
    require_once(plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'admin/class-admin.php');
    $this->Admin = new Admin();
}
```

code loading was fine, but AJAX was not working on public side, as AJAX requests bound to either `wp_ajax_` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_` actions are executed in the WP Admin context. So I decided to create my own `isAdmin()` function:

```
public static function isAdmin() {
    $currentUrl = set_url_scheme(
        sprintf(
            'http://%s%s',
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        )
    );
    $adminUrl = strtolower(admin_url());
    $referrer  = strtolower(wp_get_referer());

    if (strpos($currentUrl, $adminUrl) === 0) {
        if (strpos($referrer, $adminUrl) === 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (function_exists('wp_doing_ajax')) {
                return !wp_doing_ajax();
            } else {
                return !(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (!defined('REST_REQUEST') || !REST_REQUEST) {
            return false;
        }
        return (isset($_REQUEST['context']) && $_REQUEST['context'] === 'edit');
    }
}
```

code loading was also fine, but now AJAX was working on public side and not working on admin side.

So, how can I prevent loading public code on admin area code and vice versa with AJAX working on both sides?

Comment: Can't you just check `if ( ! is_admin() || wp_doing_ajax() )`?

Comment: @JacobPeattie No, I can't because in that case AJAX won't work on admin side. I need it to work on both sides.

Comment: How about `if ( is_admin() || wp_doing_ajax() ) { echo 'admin'; } else { echo 'blog'; }` - the echo is just for testing..

Comment: @SallyCJ In this case AJAX is not working on public side.

Comment: You can just register both the AJAX actions for admin and public/front sides. That way, regardless the current request is made on the admin or public side, your AJAX would continue to run as expected. But for the rest of your code, you can use the conditional to run/load the code only on the admin or public side.

Comment: Check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/5ally/55e760339c90df494c431a8207e20866) for a very basic example of what I mean..

Comment: So you're suggesting me to export all the AJAX code from both admin and public side and make it load out of the `is_admin()` logic? I think that will work but things will get messy when there will be many functions and classes. I was thinking some kind of custom `is_admin()` like function which would handle this. Anyway thanks for your solution <3

Comment: I'm just saying it's possible to do it the way I've mentioned. WooCommerce, for example, also does it that way. All admin and non-admin AJAX *actions* (i.e. just the callbacks, excluding enqueuing scripts, etc.) are registered when WordPress loads. But the actual callback is only executed when needed from either the admin or non-admin side of the site. But yes, I understand what you mean. Thanks for sharing your solution. Just remember that if you're releasing your plugin/theme to WordPress.org (or somewhere else), users can change the admin folder name (`wp-admin`), if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by also checking for public interface. I created new function `isPublic()` to check if it is public. So here is my final code:

```
if ($this->isPublic()) {
    require_once(plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'public/class-public.php');
    $this->Public = new Public();
} elseif ($this->isAdmin()) {
    require_once(plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'admin/class-admin.php');
    $this->Admin = new Admin();
}
```

and here are helper `isPublic()` and `isAdmin()` functions:

```
public static function isAdmin() {
    if (function_exists('is_admin') && is_admin()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') !== false) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public static function isPublic() {
    if (function_exists('is_admin') && is_admin()) {
        if (function_exists('wp_doing_ajax') && wp_doing_ajax()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') !== false) {
            if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'admin-ajax.php') !== false) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```